# Range and decimal digits

Tags: expression-manipulation, precision-and-accuracy, number-representation

When I set

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2, -1}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
    FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Range[-2, -1, 0.2], 
    Automatic}}]
```

I get on the x-axes {-2., -1.8, -1.6, -1.4, -1.2, -1.}. It seems that somehow function `N` is not recognized inside `Range`. How can I get {-2.00, -1.80, -1.60, -1.40, -1.20, -1.00}, so as every number to has two decimal digits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
PaddedForm[Range[-2, -1, 0.2], {3, 2}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2, -1},
 Frame -> True,
 Axes -> False,
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic},{Transpose[{#, Map[PaddedForm[#, {3, 2}] &, #]}] &
     [Range[-2, -1, 0.2]], Automatic}}]
```

[image]

Comment: As standalone it works but I need `Range` inside `FrameTicks` and `PaddedForm` is not compatible there. See the Edit.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z See update

Comment: Now everything is OK. Many thanks!